# How to mention will message setting in bridg.conf file of mosquitto broker

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I have installed `mosquitto` broker on ubuntu which is configured to send all the messages on an IP.

Below is the `bridge.conf` file contents:

```
connection local-ubuntu
log_type all
address 192.168.0.5:1883
remote_username admin
remote_password admin
remote_clientid dev
try_private false
cleansession false
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1.2
notifications false
keepalive_interval 36000
autosave_interval 30

topic # out 2 test/topic/ test/topic/
topic # in 2 test/topic/ test/topic/
```

I am sending all the data to broker and it is successfully publishing all the data to the mentioned IP address machine.

Now sometime this machine goes down, due to which the messages sent from the MQTT broker are not received at the machine and are lost.

I want to handle this scenario in the bridge of broker. I have read if we specify will messages then it will retain all the messages which are not delivered and will deliver them once the machine is on. But I am not able to find appropriate configuration for this.

Is there any way who has worked on this type of scenario. Please help. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from your question which of the 2 brokers you are talking about going down, do you mean the broker with this configuration or the remote broker?

Comment: @hardlib remote broker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are conflating a number of different things here.

Firstly, the Last Will and Testament message is set by a client when it connects to a broker, the broker then hangs on to this message and only publishes it if the client connection breaks (not if the client cleanly disconnects). It has no effect on if messages are queued for this client. There is no way to configure a LWT for a broker's bridge connection.

Secondly there is no need for 2 `topic` lines to configure which topics get bridged you can replace both those lines with this one:

```
topic # both 2 test/topic/ test/topic/
```

Now because you have the QOS for the topic bridging set to `2` it should already be queuing messages if the remote broker is down and it will forward these once the bridge comes back up.

If you want to check on the current status of the bridge you can subscribe to the `$SYS/broker/connection/<remote_clientid>/state` topic having set the `notifications true` option

Also, your keepalive value (10 hours) for the bridge is too high to do anything useful. On a LAN I would be using something between 10-30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually I have a remote broker which is acting as a listener. From ubuntu broker, I am sending messages to remote broker. I need to queue up messages on ubuntu broker if remote broker is offline. So as per your answer, I don't think, will message can be used in this scenario. Can you tell me what is the max number of hours keepalive value can be used ?

Comment: As I said, I'd be looking to use a keep alive value of around 10 to 30 seconds. This is just how long the broker should wait (if there are no other messages) before checking the other end of the connection is alive. If you set it to hours then you don't know the link is broken until that time expires.

Comment: The QOS 2 with `both` should mean that messages are queued on both ends if the link fails.

Comment: How can I modify it to wait for hours so that it can keep queuing the msgs and send them once online

Comment: The keep alive has **NOTHING** to do with it queuing messages, at QOS 2 it will queue any messages that are not actively acknowledged as being received.

Comment: Thank you, how long the QOS 2 will queue message.? Is there any time period for it.?

Comment: Assuming MQTT v3.x then there is no timeout or limit (other than the broker process memory)

Comment: Got it. Just one last query. Client will only be able to receive msgs if it also QOS 2 otherwise if broker is publishing with QOS 2 and client do not has QOS 2 then client will not recieve msgs.?